# asp MVC - Add a model representing user to a Partial displayed via layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

my layout page includes a header partial which changes depending on the user / company that is logged in, so it makes sense to make teh partial stronglyTyped.

I know how to call a partial and add in the model, but at what point (and where) do I add the header model? Do I need to add it on each page that uses the layout (which seems excessive), or is there some way I can add the header model without writing code on each page to add it to the viewbag and pass it through? (I suspect that if it is viable, it will have to pass through a controller somewhere. In which case, can I use an existing controller, or do I need a special 'partial header' controller?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement an action that will

1. Create the model
2. Return a ViewResult rendering your Partial with the given model

Then do an `Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")` for that action in your Layout.

Comment: Thanks. the Action needs to go into a controller so I assume that theres an overload where you can specify a controller? (Not in front of the dev pc to check at the moment)